# Two longtables side by side

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I'm trying to add two tables side by side they need to be split, cannot be multi column like `a & b & & & & c & d`

```
\begin{longtable}{cc} 
    \begin{longtable}
        \hline
        a & b\\
    \end{longtable} &

    \begin{longtable}
        \hline
        c & b\\
    \end{longtable}
\end{longtable}
```

This approach however gives me TeX capacity exceeded.

> Follow-up I am using Jinja2 template package for Python to dynamically
>   add  content to my latex file and then compile that latex file using
>   latex package for Python.
>
> Anyhow in python i do not know when I have reached the end of the
>   current page so if I use a tabular I go off the page. Longtable showed
>   promise as it automatically continues down to second page with a
>   smooth transition.
>
> Is there an alternative way to approach this ?

Comment: Why do you think multi column does not work?

Comment: I did not say it does not work. I said I cannot use it because I am adding data dynamically using Python & Jinja2 templating language. So i need tables separated.

Comment: Then: Why can't Python & Jinja2 cope with this situation?  Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: Because it over-complicates the code. I have 3 arrays that contain data I would have to rework my entire data structure and IO workflow to have 1 loop build the table like this instead of just having 3 simple loops.

Comment: Well, let me tell you something: Having two tables split over several pages in parallel will over-complicate your TeX-code, that's for sure...

Comment: I'm just starting to write the TeX-code where as I already have everything done in Python.

Comment: It's not impossible to achieve this in TeX.  But remember that Python is a programming language, while TeX is a typesetting tool (that can be misused as a programming language, of course).  So unless there are strong typesetting reasons for doing something in TeX, it is usually easier to change the data handling in Python.  You can also ask questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python, maybe that helps.  My guess would be that you would get a faster answer there.  But let's wait and see.  Good luck!

Comment: this can not work (without recoding most of latex's page breaking) for the same reason that you can not have two paragraphs breaking side by side (note two-column breaks from the bottom of one column to the top of the next not two parallel streams that each break to the corresponding column on the next page. there are packages for parallel paragraph breaking, but integrating them with loingtable woul db enon trivial

Comment: Do you have a MWE?

Comment: you can try enclose 2 longtable inside new environment (`mylongtable`) that redefine the environment `longtable` and save raws into macros and reuse the all in one `longtable`. I don't have time to do this now, may be in week-end. please give more informations in MWE, does longtables have always 2 columns? is there `hlines`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand well what you need: you need to place data of one table in compact form in the source file, then to place data of the second table and then to print these tables one next to second, they have different height and they must be breakable to pages. This can be done by the following code:

```
\newbox\tleftbox \newbox\trightbox

\def\tableleft{\setbox\tleftbox=\vbox\bgroup\tablelr}
\def\tableright{\setbox\trightbox=\vbox\bgroup\tablelr}

\def\tablelr#1{\let\\=\cr
   \halign{\vrule\strut\hbox to2em{\hss##\unskip\hss}&%
                       \hbox to2em{\strut\hss##\unskip\hss}\vrule\cr
   \noalign{\penalty0\hrule\nobreak}#1\crcr
   \noalign{\hrule\kern-.4pt\kern-\dp\strutbox}}
   \egroup
}
\def\printtables{\medskip\bgroup
   \splittopskip=0pt plus5pt \offinterlineskip
   \dimen0=\wd\tleftbox \dimen1=\wd\trightbox
   \setbox0=\vsplit\tleftbox to0pt \setbox1=\vsplit\trightbox to0pt
   \printtablesA \egroup
   \kern\dp\strutbox \medskip
}
\def\printtablesA{
   \setbox0=\vsplit\tleftbox to16pt \setbox1=\vsplit\trightbox to16pt
   \ifvoid0 \ifvoid1 \let\printtablesA=\relax \fi\fi
   \ifx\printtablesA\relax \else \hbox{\tline0\kern15pt\tline1}\fi
   \printtablesA
}
\def\tline#1{\ifvoid#1\kern\dimen#1 \else \vbox{\unvbox#1}\fi}

\vsize=3cm \raggedbottom % Just for testing

\tableleft{
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
 e & f \\
 g & h \\   
 i & j \\
 k & l \\
 m & n \\
 o & p \\   
 a & b \\
 c & d \\  
 e & f \\
 g & h \\   
 i & j \\
 k & l \\  
 m & n \\
 o & p \\   
}
\tableright{
 q & r \\
 s & t \\   
 u & v \\
 w & x \\   
 y & z \\
 q & r \\
 s & t \\
 u & v \\   
 w & x \\
 y & z \\
}
\printtables

\end
```

In order to test this, you can run `pdftex file` or you can try this with LaTeX after LaTeX commands are added (`\documentclass` etc.). You needn't any special package.

**Explanation** The tables are saved to the `\tleftbox` and `\trightbox` first. If you need more tables, you may declare a new box `\tnextbox` (for example) and you can save next table here (or you can use another more descriptive name convention). Then the macro `\printtables` does an initial setting and runs `\printtablesA` repeatedly. This macro gets the first line from `\tleftbox` and `\trightbox` and moves them to the `\box0` and `\box1` using `\vsplit` primitive. You can add analogical process for next table by `\setbox2=\vsplit\tnextbox to16pt` for example. If all boxes are empty:

```
\ifvoid0 \ifvoid1 \ifvoid2 \let\printtablesA=\relax \fi\fi\fi
```

then the loop ends. The line constructed by `\box0`, `\box1` is printed to the output using `\hbox` and `\tline` macro. For three tables it looks like

```
\hbox{\tline0\kern15pt\tline1\kern15pt\tline2}
```

The horizontal space between tables is specified here (15pt). The output is filled by such `\hbox`es and the list of these `\hbox`es is breakable into pages, of course.

Comment: Helped me. If you could add bit explanation of adding more than two if possible and what's going on I will accept as the answer and grant the bounty.

Comment: \hline breaks the tables vertical alignment the one with less items gets pushed down. Is it possible to have this table have all cells bordered ?

Answer (score 0):

While Python cannot *know* when the table has reached the bottom of the page, it can make a very good guess.  If all your entries have the same size more or less, you can just count the number of rows in your table and start a new table every `n` rows, where `n` depends on the geometry of your page, your font size, the entries to the table, etc.

Depending on the content of your table, it might also help the reader, if you always put the same number of rows on each page.  Then, if you look for a specific row, you can estimate on which page you have to look.

Comment: I want to consider Python solution as the last option.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

Take the following usepackages

`longtable`, `datatool`. Designing a table which can handle your task seems to be possible.
There are a lot of questions unanswered.

What if table one is much longer than table 2 ?
What if table one is much shorter than table 2 ?
How do you want to handle this cases?

Maybe I have a solution for you, but currently I have to guess.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,import,hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={a,b,c,d}]{ex}{data.csv} 
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|cccc|c|c|}\hline
\DTLforeach{ex}{\a=a, \b=b,\c=c,\d=d}%
            {%
            \DTLiffirstrow{}%
                {%
                    \\%
                }%
             \protect\a&%
             \protect\b&&&&&\protect\c&\protect\d%
            }%
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

You should adapt the longtable header, firstheader, firstfooter, lastfooter...
If you want to change distance, load array and define new columntypes....

If you need more information, feel free to contact me....

Comment: Tables should just be top aligned and then extend down I think `[t]` It does not matter if one extends half the first page and other extends 3 pages and leaves lots of white space.

Comment: Tell me about the structure, is there always the same amount of columns and only rows will change?

Comment: Yes column amount it always the same. Row amount is different each row has only one line in it well only one character (A or B or C or D). And all 3 tables are fully bordered.